# Using OpenIE to extract triples from command line

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a modestly sized file (~1.5 GB) of free text and I am hoping to use OpenIE to extract triples, but I'm currently having a few problems.

I invoke it using the following command:

```
java -mx2g  -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE ./my_file.txt
```

The first issue is that this uses *a lot* of memory. I get java memory issues even if I allow 50GB using `-mx50g`.

The second issue is that it does not seem to write the output to a file, it only dumps it to the console. The only way to get the result into a file is to redirect the output into a file.

This is my first time using the package, so I'm not sure if I'm just doing something dumb. Is this memory usage correct and how do I save the results to a file?

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, under what definition is 1.5G "modestly sized"!?

But more to the point, I recommend (1) breaking up the file into smaller documents, and then (2) annotating the smaller documents with the `-filelist` option. You can then (3) redirect the output to a file with the `-output` option. In more detail:

1. The easiest way to split up the file is with something like the [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) command. If you want to maintain sentence or paragraph boundaries, I'd recommend running the document through CoreNLP's tokenizer and splitting that way (set the annotators to `tokenize,ssplit`). This'll require less space than the full pipeline, though likely still on the order of a few ten GB for a 1.5GB file.
2. If you construct a file listing all of the files you want to annotate, one per line, you can pass them to OpenIE via the `-filelist` option. For example, a file with contents:

   ```
   file1
   file2
   file3
   ```

   would annotate file1, file2, and file3 with OpenIE extractions.
3. You can save the output tuples to a file with the `-output` option. You can also specify the format you want with `-format`: one of `default`, `ollie`, `reverb`, or `qa_srl`. The format that gives the most information -- but is also the most space-intensive -- is `reverb`. If you want a minimal set of extractions that span as large a subject+object as possible, use `qa_srl`.